# How to reset state with event.target.value and make it persist on multiple <li>

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to grab the user input on key pressed and pass it to that list above next. I feel like there must be a way to reset the state and make it persist, but I just can't figure it out? How can I understand this?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';
import '../sign.css';

const VALUES = [
  { id: 1, label: "name", text: "Hi, What is your Name?", placeholder: "Enter your full name" },
  { id: 2, label: "uname", text: "What shall we call you?", placeholder: "Enter a username" },
  { id: 3, label: "email", text: "Enter you email", placeholder: "Email" },
  { id: 4, label: "password", text: "Choose a password", placeholder: "make sure you dont forget" },
  { id: 5, label: "signup", text: "sign up", placeholder: ""},
];


export default function SignUp() {
  
  const [show, setShow] = useState(VALUES)
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [show]);
  
  const onKeyPressed = (ev, id) => {
    if (ev.charCode === 13) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      const nextRender = currentIndex + 1;
      if (nextRender < show.length) {
        setCurrentIndex(nextRender);
        setDetails(ev.target.value);
      } else {
        //todo
      }
    }
  }
  const displayItem = useMemo(() => show[currentIndex], [show, currentIndex]);
 
  return (
    <div className="container" id="container">
      <div className="navigation">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#"  dataref="name">{this should display their name}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  dataref="uname">{this should display their username}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  dataref="email">{this should display their email}</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <form id="sign-form" className="sign-form">
        <ol className="questions">
          {
            <li onKeyPress={(KeyboardEvent) => onKeyPressed(KeyboardEvent, displayItem.id)} key={displayItem.id} >
              <span><label htmlFor={displayItem.label}>{displayItem.text}</label></span>
              <input id={displayItem.id} name={displayItem.label} type="text" placeholder={displayItem.placeholder} autoFocus/>
            </li>
          };  
        </ol>
     </form>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: So what's the issue you are having? I don't understand the question

Comment: @szczocik i just edited the question, tks :)

Comment: @szczocik i want setDetails to grab ev.target.value from the input and display on the lis above, but i can only make setDetails display the user name 3 times, and i want it to display name, username, and email on keypress.

Comment: Oh right. So you want to display details in the first list you have there inside the navigation class, right? What's the structure of details. If it's got the right properties, you can just do ```{details.name}``` etc

Comment: @szczocik yeah, right, i guess i am not sure how to make that? i thought i could just use an empty string, and reset to new value each time?

Comment: But that would override previous value. You want probably an object and whenever you call setDetails, you want to spread details and add new property

Comment: i am really confused how to make that using event.targets. setDetails({...ev.target.value}) is clearly not what you meant, is it?

Comment: Maybe more like this ```setDetails({...details, name: ev.target.value})```. You would need to change name to map to the right priperty though based on the input

Comment: so like setDetails({...details, name: ev.target.value, username: ev.target.value, email: ev.target.value})? that also sets username and email to their name...

Comment: @szczocik i just tried to setDetails 3 times, but I guess that's alsonot right... `setDetails({...details, name: ev.target.value});
        setDetails({...details, username: ev.target.value});
        setDetails({...details, email: ev.target.value});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I think I know what you mean now. I've run the code in CodeSandbox and it makes sense. You want to do like a stepper for your registration where you ask a single question at a time.

Storing values in an object would still be a preferable way of doing this. But you need to get the label for the value and append it to the existing object. You can build your object with data when you go through your stepper.

Here is a working solution. Hopefully that's what you were looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pasteur-76xux4?file=/src/App.js

I modified the onKeyPressed to grab the label from VALUES array based on the index we are currently on. Then that label is used as a key inside of the object where the value is the value from the event handler

```
 const onKeyPressed = (ev, id) => {
    if (ev.charCode === 13) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      const label = show[currentIndex].label; // grab the label based on the current index
      const nextRender = currentIndex + 1;
      if (nextRender < show.length) {
        setCurrentIndex(nextRender);
        setDetails({ ...details, [label]: ev.target.value }); // add the value to the details object where key is the label
      } else {
        //todo
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much... that's exaclty what i was trying to figure out. You rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

I let you the code that it works like I think that you want

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';

const VALUES = [
  { id: 1, label: "name", text: "Hi, What is your Name?", placeholder: "Enter your full name" },
  { id: 2, label: "uname", text: "What shall we call you?", placeholder: "Enter a username" },
  { id: 3, label: "email", text: "Enter you email", placeholder: "Email" },
  { id: 4, label: "password", text: "Choose a password", placeholder: "make sure you dont forget" },
  { id: 5, label: "signup", text: "sign up", placeholder: ""},
];


export default function SignUp() {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(VALUES)
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {

  }, [show]);

  const onKeyPressed = ( ev, id ) => {
    if (ev.charCode === 13) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      const nextRender = currentIndex + 1;
      if (nextRender < show.length) {
        setCurrentIndex(nextRender);
        const label = VALUES[currentIndex].label;
        details[label] = ev.target.value;
        setDetails(details);
      } else {
        //todo
      }
    }
  }
  const displayItem = useMemo(() => show[currentIndex], [show, currentIndex]);

  return (
    <div className="container" id="container">
      <div className="navigation">
        <ol>
          {Object.keys(details).map((key) => (
            <li><a href="#" dataref={key}>{key}: {details[key]}</a></li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
      <form id="sign-form" className="sign-form">
        <ol className="questions">
          <li onKeyPress={( KeyboardEvent ) => onKeyPressed(KeyboardEvent, displayItem.id)} key={displayItem.id}>
            <span><label htmlFor={displayItem.label}>{displayItem.text}</label></span>
            <input id={displayItem.id} name={displayItem.label} type="text" placeholder={displayItem.placeholder}
                   autoFocus/>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```